# ¿Por qué este error "NotImplementedError: data_source='2017-1-4' is not implemented"

Tags: jupyter, python-3.8, plotly

Estoy aprendiendo clases. Intento crear una clase que muestre gráficas de diferentes tipos. El script es:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as pdr 
import datetime as dt
from datetime import date
from plotly.offline import iplot
import plotly.express as px 

class ImportadorCotizaciones:

    def __init__(self):
        self.cotizaciones = None
        self.start = "2017-1-4"
        self.end = date.today()
        self.cotizaciones = None

    def Importar_cotizaciones(self):

        dicc_tickers = {"IBE.MC":"Iberdrola", "TEF.MC":"Telefonica", "^IBEX":"Ibex35" }
        dfs = []
        nombres = []

        for (k,v) in dicc_tickers.items():
            self.cotizaciones_de_ticker = pdr.DataReader(k, self.start, self.end)
            self.cotizaciones_de_ticker = self.cotizaciones_de_ticker[["Close"]]
            self.cotizaciones_de_ticker = self.cotizaciones_de_ticker.rename(columns={"Close": v})

            dfs.append(self.cotizaciones_de_ticker)

        dfs = iter(dfs)
        self.cotizaciones = next(dfs)
        for df_ in dfs:
            self.cotizaciones = self.cotizaciones.merge(df_, on='Date')

class mostrar_gráficos:
    def __init__(self, importador):
        self.importador = importador 
    
    def dibujar_graficos(self):
        self.aux_val_ind = importador.cotizaciones[["Iberdrola", "Ibex35"]].pct_change().dropna() 
        df = self.aux_val_ind.copy(deep=True)
        df['Media'] = df.mean(axis = 1)        
        return px.line((df + 1).cumprod() ,y=df.columns ,title=f"Valor de 1€ invertido desde el { importador.start}  hasta el {importador.end} ")

importador = ImportadorCotizaciones()
importador.Importar_cotizaciones()
importador.cotizaciones[:3] 

mostrar = mostrar_gráficos(importador)
mostrar.dibujar_graficos()
```

En su ejecución, me devuelve el error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-98bcb1ab1600> in <module>
     43 
     44 importador = ImportadorCotizaciones()
---> 45 importador.Importar_cotizaciones()
     46 importador.cotizaciones[:3]
     47 

<ipython-input-30-98bcb1ab1600> in Importar_cotizaciones(self)
     21 
     22         for (k,v) in dicc_tickers.items():
---> 23             self.cotizaciones_de_ticker = pdr.DataReader(k, self.start, self.end)
     24             self.cotizaciones_de_ticker = self.cotizaciones_de_ticker[["Close"]]
     25             self.cotizaciones_de_ticker = self.cotizaciones_de_ticker.rename(columns={"Close": v})

~/anaconda3/envs/enri/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    197                 else:
    198                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 199             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    200 
    201         return cast(F, wrapper)

~/anaconda3/envs/enri/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas_datareader/data.py in DataReader(name, data_source, start, end, retry_count, pause, session, api_key)
    371     if data_source not in expected_source:
    372         msg = "data_source=%r is not implemented" % data_source
--> 373         raise NotImplementedError(msg)
    374 
    375     if data_source == "yahoo":

NotImplementedError: data_source='2017-1-4' is not implemented
```

¿Cuál puede ser la causa?. Agradeceré ayuda.

Comment: Por lo que pone en el error, te falta un parámetro en `DataReader`. Revisa la documentación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ampliando el comentario de ChemaCrotes, cuando se ejecuta `self.cotizaciones_de_ticker = pdr.DataReader(k, v, self.start, self.end)` la función `pdr.DataReader` **requiere una fuente** (es decir el nombre de una compañía) para pasarle los datos, mientras que tú le estás pasando una fecha.

Es decir esta linea de código debería ser así:

```
self.cotizaciones_de_ticker = pdr.DataReader(k, "Nombre_compañia", self.start, self.end)
```